# 415 Unsupported Media Type - JAVA SpringBoot - Entidades con listas de entidades

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, postman

Actualizo:  el problema son las listas en Alumno y Profesor. Son los atributos tipo Lista se envían bien los datos y no retorna ningún error. Sigo averiguando cómo poder solucionar esto.
Estoy realizando Una API de práctica y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:
Me estaban funcionando bien los 4 métodos convencionales (get, post, put, delete) pero al momento de agregar en las entidades listas de otra entidad, Postman comenzó a retornar el error "message":
"Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported".
Sucede lo mismo con todas las entidades: Profesor, Alumno, Curso. Profesor y Alumno heredan de Persona. Les adjunto el código.

Clase Persona:

```
package com.school.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@MappedSuperclass
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class Persona implements Serializable{

    private String nombre;
    private String email;
    private String dni;
    private String domicilio;
        

}
```

Clase Alumno

```
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Alumno extends Persona implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_Alumno;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alumno")
    private List<AlumnoRRSS> redesSocialAlumno;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Curso> cursos = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Clase Curso

```
package com.school.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties("id_Curso")
public class Curso implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_Curso;

    private String nombre_Curso;

    private String descripcion;

    @Column
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cursos")
    private Set<Alumno> alumnos;

    @Column
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cursodictado")
    private Set<Profesor> profesores;

}
```

Clase Profesor

```
package com.school.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Profesor extends Persona implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_Profesor;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Curso> cursodictado ;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profesor")
    private List<ProfesorRRSS> redesSocialProfesor;

}
```

Clase Red Social

```
package com.school.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class RedSocial implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_RedSocial;

    @NotBlank
    private String nombre;

    @NotBlank
    private String icono;
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "redSocial")
    private AlumnoRRSS alumnoRRSS;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "redSocial")
    private ProfesorRRSS profesorRRSS;

}
```

Alumno Controller

```
package com.school.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.school.error.CustomError;
import com.school.model.Alumno;
import com.school.service.AlumnoService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/api/alumnos")
public class AlumnoController {

    @Autowired
    AlumnoService alumnoService;

    // busqueda de todos los alumnos o por nombre con param
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Alumno>> getAlumnos(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {

        List<Alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();

        if (name == null) {
            alumnos = alumnoService.getAll();
            if (alumnos.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity(new CustomError("No existen alumnos"), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Alumno>>(alumnos, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            alumnos = alumnoService.getByName(name);
            if (alumnos.size() >= 1) {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<Alumno>>(alumnos, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity(new CustomError("No existe el alumno solicitado"), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
    }

    // Post
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Alumno> addAlumno(@RequestBody Alumno alumno, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {
        try {
            alumnoService.create(alumno);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setLocation(
                    uriComponentsBuilder.path("/v1/api/alumnos/{id}").buildAndExpand(alumno.getId_Alumno()).toUri());
            return new ResponseEntity<Alumno>(alumno, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String mensaje = "Error: " + e.getMessage() + e.getMessage();
            return new ResponseEntity(mensaje, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }

    // Ver un registro con por ID
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Alumno> getAlumnoById(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long idAlumno)  {
    try {
        Alumno alumno = alumnoService.getById(idAlumno);
        return new ResponseEntity<Alumno>(alumno, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        String mensaje = "Error: " + e.getMessage() + e.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity(mensaje, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    }

    // Actualizar un registro
    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Alumno> patchAlumno(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long idAlumno, @RequestBody Alumno alumno) {
        if (idAlumno == null || idAlumno <= 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new CustomError("No se ingreso un id de alumno valido"), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        try {
            Alumno alumnoAux;
            alumnoAux = alumnoService.getById(idAlumno);
            
            if (alumnoAux == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity(new CustomError("No existe el alumno"), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }
            alumnoAux = Alumno.builder().nombre(alumno.getNombre()).dni(alumno.getDni()).domicilio(alumno.getDomicilio())
                    .email(alumno.getEmail()).id_Alumno(idAlumno).build();
            
            alumnoService.update(alumnoAux);
            
            return new ResponseEntity<Alumno>(alumno, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String mensaje = "Error: " + e.getMessage() + e.getMessage();
            return new ResponseEntity(mensaje, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

    }

    public ResponseEntity<List<Alumno>> insertCursoEnAlumno(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "idCurso", required = false) Long nameidCurso) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Clase ProfesorRRSS

```
package com.school.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="profesor_rrss")
public class ProfesorRRSS {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_nick;

    private String nickname;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_RedSocial")
    private RedSocial redSocial;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_Profesor")
    private Profesor profesor;

}
```

Clase AlumnoRRSS

La excepción que arroja POSTMAN es la siguiente:

```
package com.school.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "alumno_rrss")
public class AlumnoRRSS {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_nick;

    private String nickname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_RedSocial")
    private RedSocial redSocial;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_Alumno")
    private Alumno alumno;
    


}

"trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported\n\tat
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:206)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\n\tat 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\n\tat 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)\n\tat
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat 
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\n",
```

El repo de git del proyecto es https://github.com/lcotarelo/School-API.git

Comment: En Java usar Snake_Case (`Alumno_y_RRSS`) es delito (o algo así). Los nombres de clase se escriben en PascalCase, cada palabra en mayúsculas y sin espacios ni guiones bajos y los atributos van en camelCase, la primera en minúscula y las palabras siempre juntas sin espacios y con las iniciales mayúsculas. Si no coincide con el nombre que tiene en tu base de datos, hay mappings para poder cambiarlo como `@Column(name = "id_RedSocial") private Long idRedSocial;` Esto hace el código muchísimo más legible (especialmente por otros que estamos acostumbrados a eso!). Un saludo

Comment: Un par de consejos: Si tienes un error o excepción, pon todo el texto (todo el *stack trace* en la pregunta. Suelen incluir mucha información para saber qué está pasando). Por otro lado, no hace falta que las clases implementen "Serializable" a menos que vayas a enviar datos *binarios*. Si se van a enviar como JSON, es innecesario

Comment: corregidos los cambios que me comentaron

Comment: El problema con el código lo tienes con la anotación `@JsonBackReference` porque la documentación especifica con que no se puede utilizar con Colleciones, Mapas, Array y Enums, agrega las Clases AlumnoRRSS y ProfesorRRSS  para que pueda realizar la corrección de la recursividad.

Comment: agregadas las clases AlumnoRRSS y ProfesorRRSS y removidos los jsonbackreference de las Colleciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SOLUCIONADO -

Borre los @JsonManagedReference y a los @jsonbackreference les agregue el (value=“valor”)

En el repo del primer post está actualizado.

Comment: No usamos etiquetas en el título para indicar que algo está solucionado, el título se queda como estaba y se marca la respuesta que lo arregla como aceptada y ya está. Como es tu propia respuesta, no te dejará aceptarla hasta pasadas 24h creo, pero luego puedes aceptarla sin problema.

Comment: 48 horas, para ser exactos. Y tampoco se agregan etiquetas en las respuestas: solo [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) y listo.